# Prometheus duration collection

Tags: histogram, monitoring, prometheus

Is it possible calculate operation duration in prometheus when the data is collected as start time (epoch) and end time (epoch) that would be grouped by some form of a transaction trace?

Once duration is known, the data can then be used to provide a prometheus Apdex.

Use case:

1. API initiates fires (and essentially forgets) a start operation request
2. Multiple distributed (message based) processes take place
3. Final message fires and indicates the end of the operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus is a metrics-based system, not a tracing system. The most you can do is track a summary of how long all your requests are taking using the `Summary` or `Histogram` metric types.

Comment: Yeah so thinking that some other tool would have to extract the duration of an operation and then said that over Prometheus for use in Histogram / Apdex ?

Comment: You should use a Prometheus client library within the application to provide that.